# Google Drive Backup and Sync - sync or restore "My Computer" folder

Tags: google-drive, backup

Does the first part of the new Backup and Sync App from Google simply backup "My Computer" or "My Laptop"?

And only the second part of the settings "Google Drive" can sync between devices?

[image: Google backup and sync settings]

It would be nice, if one could sync the backup folders. Example

- Google Drive Folder: D:/Google Drive
- Also synced Folder: C:/some_folder

From Testing I can still only sync contents within Google Drive. "My Computer" is simply backed up to the cloud, which is a shame.

Moreover, how would I restore the backup folders on my machine if I had to reset the machine?

The documentation is not very clear.

Comment: As your question is about the file synchronization/backup feature of Google Drive, and not the web interface, your question is more appropriate for [su].

Answer (score 1):

> Does the first part of the new Backup and Sync App from Google simply backup "My Computer" or "My Laptop"?

No. Just like the 'other sync' it is bi-directional. You can create a file in your local "test" folder and it will appear in Drive, and you can make a file in the remote location and it will appear in your local "test" folder.

Note however that the remote destination is under "Computers->your device" on the lefthand side of the Drive UI. This 'folder' cannot be selected as a sync target by a third party (i.e. another device). So you can choose to sync either:

- any folder(s) on a device and forfeit multi-device syncing (view 1- My Laptop),
- or (view 2- Google Drive) sync in the original way to a drive folder(s) that can sync multiple devices, but forfeit the filesystem convenience since you have to put everything under a local Google Drive folder.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the first part of the new Backup and Sync App from Google simply
>   backup "My Computer" or "My Laptop"? And only the second part of the
>   settings "Google Drive" can sync between devices?

The first part just let you specify which folders on your local device you want to be backed up to cloud. Its just its name is "My Computer"; if you are using it on a laptop, it refer to your laptop. The second part enables you to choose which items from the cloud to sync back to local device (your laptop).

> It would be nice, if one could sync the backup folders. Example
>
> Google Drive Folder: D:/Google Drive
>
> Also synced Folder: C:/some_folder
>
> From Testing I can still only sync contents within Google Drive. "My
>   Computer" is simply backed up to the cloud, which is a shame.

"D:/Google Drive" is the source to be backed up to cloud and it can also be local location storing the files sync from cloud; "C:/some_folder" can be the source to be backed up to cloud too. "My Computer" tab in Google Drive is just a tab used for saving files backed up from local.
Tip: Usually, files from local to cloud, Backup and Sync calls it "backup"; files from cloud to local, Backup and Sync calls it "sync".(personal understanding)

> Moreover, how would I restore the backup folders on my machine if I
>   had to reset the machine?

If you reset your machine, reinstall Backup and Sync and reestablish the backup and sync service, files in "My Computer" tab in Google Drive will be automatically restored (synced) to your local storage.